# Cannot configure pytest in my simple project

Tags: python, django, pytest

i have the folowing project structure, but when trying to run pytest in console i get error.
Is the problem in pytest.ini?

```
ERROR backend/tests/test_user.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call

backend
  |-foodgram
        |-foodgram
        |-manage.py
  |-api
  |-users
  |-tests
  |-pytest.ini
```

in my **pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
python_paths = foodgram/
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = foodgram.settings
norecursedirs = env/*
addopts = -vv -p no:cacheprovider
testpaths = tests/
python_files = test_*.py
```

Comment: topic up. Any thoughts would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installed additional packages

```
pytest-pythonpath
```